# Button coloring one by one

Tags: javascript, html, button, colors

Im using javascript to color the buttons, but I wanna get to the point when one button is pressed all the others are greyed (set to the default color)

This is where i stand:

Javascript:

```
function changeBtn(btn) {
    if (! btn.style)
    {
        alert("Err!");
        return;
    }
    btn.style.background = "#acd484";
    return;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input class="submit" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size:12px;" id "submit" type="button" value="Zivljensko" onclick="changeBtn(this)" />
<input class="submit" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size:12px;" id "submit" type="button" value="Premozenjsko" onclick="changeBtn(this)" />
<input class="submit" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size:12px;" id "submit" type="button" value="Best doctors" onclick="changeBtn(this)" />
<input class="submit" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size:12px;" id "submit" type="button" value="Splosne info" onclick="changeBtn(this)" />
<input class="submit" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size:12px;" id "submit" type="button" value="Splosne info" onClick="changeBtn(this)" />
```

And this is submit class if its needed:

```
.submit {
    border-top:     1px solid #ffffff;
    border-left:        1px solid #ffffff;
    border-right:       1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:      1px solid #000000;
    padding:        0px 20px !important;
    font-size:      11px !important;
    background-color:   #fff;
    font-weight:        bold;
    color:          #453;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas if you understand what Im trying to accomplish :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set all buttons other buttons to grey except the one that was clicked, the easiest way is to grab all of the buttons based on the `submit` class, then iterate over them and set the color. Do this before you set the green color.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hmBxe/)**

```
function changeBtn(btn){
    if (!btn.style)
    {
        alert("Err!");
        return;
    }
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.submit');
    for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[i].style.background = 'grey';   
    }

    btn.style.background = "#acd484";
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("submit").onclick = function() { 

var allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("submit");
var count = allButtons.length;

for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
{
  if(this != allButtons[i])
    allButtons[i].style.background = "grey";
}

};
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using jQuery

change your function with this one

```
function changeBtn(btn) {
  $(".submit").removeClass("selected");
  $(btn).addClass("selected")
}
```

and your css

```
.submit {
    border-top:     1px solid #ffffff;
    border-left:        1px solid #ffffff;
    border-right:       1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:      1px solid #000000;
    padding:        0px 20px !important;
    font-size:      11px !important;
    background-color:   #fff;
    font-weight:        bold;
    color:          #453;
}

.selected {
  background-color:#acd484;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/diqadu/1/edit)